# How to setup PCMCIA card/socket services in DOS

Tags: services, ms-dos, pcmcia

I have an old DOS based PLC program that I need to run with a PCMCIA card for communication. I can't find instructions for how to do that anywhere.

Laptop: Dell Latitude C800
Card: PCMK1794 (Allen-Bradly)

Does anyone know how to setup the card and socket services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cardsoft Services](https://archive.org/details/systemsoft_cardsoft_3.0_dos_windows)

download and install the following program and copy all files to formatted floppy then follow these instructions

```
   1.  Boot to a DOS Prompt (C:\) and insert the PCMCIA or XP-PCM diskette into drive A:.
   2. Type A: and press Enter.
   3. Type Install and press Enter.
   4. You will be given a prompt to press Esc to quit or any other key to continue. Press Enter to continue.
   5. A menu of four choices will appear. First Time Install will be highlighted in gray. Press Enter to select this option.
   6. You will be given a new menu, with Standard Installation highlighted in gray. Press Enter to select this option.
   7. The installation will ask how many PCMCIA Sockets are in your system. Press the down arrow key to highlight the number 2. Press Enter.
   8. Press Enter to select Drive C: as the destination drive.
   9. Press Enter to accept \CARDSOFT as the directory for installation and press Enter once more to confirm this selection.
  10. Once the installation finishes copying files to your hard drive, it will ask to modify your CONFIG.SYS file. Press Enter to accept this and then press Enter again to confirm the process.
  11. You will be prompted to press Esc to continue or any other key to continue. Press Enter to continue.
  12. Again, you will be prompted to press Esc to continue or any other key to continue. Press Enter to continue.
  13. It will prompt you to remove any PC Cards presently in the system. Remove any cards in the unit and press Enter to continue.
  14. You will see a message that Card Services Allocation Utility has completed. Press Enter and then press Enter again to exit to DOS.
  15. The installation will place you in C:\CARDSOFT. Type CD \ and then press Enter.
  16. Type edit config.sys and press Enter.
  17. Locate the line that reads either: device=c:\dos\emm386.exe noems or device=c:\windows\emm386.exe noems
  18. Make this line end as follows: noems x=d000-dfff (three zeros not the letter O)
  19. Use the down arrow key to scroll down until you find the line that reads: REM CardSoft (TM) 3.1 PCMCIA DRIVERS
  20. The following 4 lines are necessary for the PCMCIA slots to work. Delete any extra lines that are in this section:
      DEVICEHIGH=C:\CARDSOFT\SSVADEM.EXE
      DEVICEHIGH=C:\CARDSOFT\CS.EXE
      DEVICEHIGH=C:\CARDSOFT\CSALLOC.EXE
      DEVICEHIGH=C:\CARDSOFT\CARDID.EXE
  21. Press the Alt key then F. Choose Save and press Enter.
  22. Press the Alt key then F. Choose Exit and press Enter.
  23. You will be returned to a C:\ Prompt. Shut the system down with the power switch and eject the diskette from the floppy drive.
  24. Wait 10 seconds and power the unit up normally. You will see the lines for PCMCIA support load as the unit boots.
```

[http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA01030641.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20110629010349/http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA01030641.htm)

and you should be on your way...

as well if your having problems with the installation of your cardservices and socket services just change the `DEVICEHIGH=C:\CARDSOFT\SSVADEM.EXE` files to other ones in the cardsoft directory (prefix "SS" stands for Socket Services and "CS" stands for Card Services)

this took me a good half a week to implement because information on this problem is so rare hope it helps you out!